# Python - JSON to nested and flatten dictionary

Tags: python, dictionary, recursion, nested, flatten

I'm new in Python and currently trying to read the following JSON:

```
"level1_key1":"1",
"level1_key2":{
    "level2_key1":"2",
    "level2_key2":{
        "level3_key1":"Max depth"
    }
}
```

then put it in a dictionary (done by now) and finally show it as nested and flatten (I'm using Python 3.6). I want to do it with recursion and avoid using third party libraries. I tried all the suggestions from StackOverflow but can't make the result look like the one from the task which is:

```
Nested dict: {u'level1_key2': {u'level2_key2': {u'level3_key1': u'Max depth'}, u'level2_key1': u'2'}, u'level1_key1': u'1'}
Flatten dict: {u'level2_key1': u'2', u'level3_key1': u'Max depth', u'level1_key1': u'1'}
```

I'd much appreciate any help. Thanks in advance!

Answer (score 0):

Please try below code. It should solve your query.

```
example_dict = {"level1_key1":"1",
                    "level1_key2":{
                        "level2_key1":"2",
                        "level2_key2":{
                            "level3_key1":"Max depth"
                        }
                     }
                 }   

flatten_dict = {}
def process_dict(dict_val):
    for key, val in dict_val.items():
        if isinstance(val, dict) and val:
            process_dict(val)
        else:
            flatten_dict.update({key:val})
    return flatten_dict

print process_dict(example_dict)
```

The Answer:

> {'level2_key1': '2', 'level3_key1': 'Max depth', 'level1_key1': '1'}

Comment: Hello and thanks for your answer.
Unfortunately when I try to execute, I get the following error: 

Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "file.py", line 73, in <module>
    print(process_dict(example_dict))
  File "file.py", line 64, in process_dict
    for key, val in dict_val.iteritems():
AttributeError: 'dict' object has no attribute 'iteritems'

Could it be something with the Python version?

Comment: I just saw that iteritems() is now items() on Python 3. Edited it but not getting the desired result. Thanks anyway for the answer, I'm gonna keep trying.

Comment: What result are you getting?

Comment: Hello again. This is a gist with the code and result - https://gist.github.com/aktan4uk/b6f6f93d18d29d585099f1087bda065e

Comment: Remove the print statement which prints key,value and try. I have updated the same above also.

Comment: Thanks. Now it is {'level1_key1': '1', 'level2_key1': '2', 'level3_key1': 'Max depth'}
Anyway, much appreciated!

Comment: Can you mark my answer as the answer and close the question

Answer (score 0):

You can use `dict.items` in recursion:

```
d =  {u'level1_key2': {u'level2_key2': {u'level3_key1': u'Max depth'}, u'level2_key1': u'2'}, u'level1_key1': u'1'}
def flatten(d):
   _r = [[(a, b)] if not isinstance(b, dict) else flatten(b) for a, b in d.items()]
   return [i for b in _r for i in b]

new_d = dict(flatten(d))
```

Output:

```
{'level3_key1': 'Max depth', 'level2_key1': '2', 'level1_key1': '1'}
```

Comment: Thanks for the answer. Unfortunately with this code I get the following: {'level1_key1': '1', 'level2_key1': '2', 'level3_key1': 'Congrats you have reached the maximum dept of the dict'}
Probably it is something on my end I'm doing wrong...